# Is there any way to display tooltip dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

Microsoft documentation about [tooltip](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip?view=net-5.0) says:

> If you call the SetToolTip method multiple times for a specified control, the tooltip text for control is no longer displayed.

Well, I have a block of code like this:

```cs
private void UpdateTooltips()
{
  this.toolTip.SetToolTip(this.controlA, "A");
  this.toolTip.SetToolTip(this.controlB, "B");
  this.toolTip.SetToolTip(this.controlC, "C");
  this.toolTip.SetToolTip(this.controlD, "D");
  ...

}
```

And indeed the tooltip is not showing. I am wondering whether there is a way to dynamically change the tooltip info in several different controls like the method above. The Tooltips can be updated in run time.

Comment: Are you looking for [LastToolTip.Show](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show) on [ControlMouseHover](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover) or [ToolTip.ShowAlways](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.showalways): [Tutorial C# Corner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/tooltip-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: @OlivierRogier, I tried that already. No success.

Comment: Have you tried multiple tooltips, one for each control?

Comment: Yeah, it works that way. But the number of controls can be several of them...

Comment: Can you refactor for example to parse on name of controls or using a list or any criteria?

Comment: what do you mean with refactor?

Comment: Using for example a loop to create a tooltip and assign it to a controls list, so you will have very few lines.

Comment: Yeah, it works as I said. But it can generate some memory leaks, many 'new' created.

Comment: Why do you fear of memory leaks? Do you have billions of tooltips?

Comment: Threre are some opened question here in SO about it. That's why I am avoiding it. Not billions, for sure. but hundreds of it.

Comment: What happens if you create hundreds of tooltips with such a dynamic generation loop? Does it work? Does it lag? Does it crash?

Comment: But why should I do that way if it is a wrong implementation? If somehow this provides problems, means it is a wrong way to do it, isn't it? Today is hundreds, but tomorrow can be more.

Comment: I tested the generation of 10,000 buttons each having its tooltip. It takes 20s (because of the Controls.Add in fact), but after that everything works fine except the window switch which has ~2s of latency (because of the controls amount in fact). With 200 buttons, the generation takes 2.5s, and the windows changing lag is less than 1s on my Win10 x64 Core i7-4770 GTX970. So you should be able to use it, otherwise the problem is not with the number of tooltips but with the number of controls itself. I have a software that show +1000 dynamic complex textboxes: it works slightly slow but usable.

Comment: But if you want to have only one tooltip, assigning MouseHover or Enler+Leave event handlers for each controls, to call Show(sender...) (then hide if using enter+leave) in this method is a standard pattern. I don't understand why you said it does not work.

Comment: Where have you found quoted in the documentation?? I found: _Calling the SetToolTip method more than once for a given control does not specify multiple ToolTip text to display for a control, but instead changes the current ToolTip text for the control._

Comment: You are pointing to the German documentation and probably see a translated version. If you look into the original English documentation, in the [Remaks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#remarks) section: *Calling the SetToolTip method more than once for a given control does not specify multiple ToolTip text to display for a control, but instead changes the current ToolTip text for the control.*

Comment: And modifying the tooltip of a control is very straightforward, for example: `toolTip1.SetToolTip(button1, DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());`. Another fact is, even when you load the form, the tooltip of the controls will be set at run-time, by calling Initializecomponent method in constructor, using exactly the same method, `SetTooltip`. So if your code doesn't work, you need to find the problem somewhere else. Share a [MCVE] and maybe someone is able to help you if you are able to reproduce the problem in a minimal code.